# How can I show the label next to the bar in r highcharter?

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I am trying to create a bar chart where the x-axis labels are located next to the bars.
My desired result would be similar to:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuPIV.png]
(from: [HighCharts Place Label on Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698955/highcharts-place-label-on-bar))

However, there are two differences:

- I am making my chart in R highcharter
- I don't wan't the labels inside the bars, but next to them. It should look similar to how you would normally add a value next to a bar, see [for example](https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/04135759/chart-4.png):

[image]

I have tried offsetting the labels, but since I don't want them to be on a fixed position, but on a position relative to the bars, this did not work.

I have also tried to use annotations, but I'm not fimiliar enough with those to get it to work properly. My original example allows the user to select a specific series. So the location has to be dynamic,but when I use the annotations I can only get them to appear at a fixed point.

Here is a very basic example of what my chart looks like:

```
library(highcharter)

#create dataframe
data <- data.frame(
  type_1 = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"),
  type_2 = c("1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2"),
  n = c(5,8,10,4,7,9))
data

# create chart
highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series(data, type = "bar", hcaes(x = type_1, group = type_2, y = n)) %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(series = list(stacking = 'normal')) %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = unique(data$type_1)
```

What I would like is for the a / b/ c not to appear in the legend, but to be shown next to the bar.

Thank you for any help you could offer!

Comment: What do you want where? Type_1 to be to the left of the bars and then type_2 to be immediately to the right end of each bar?

Comment: Right now all of you're displaying the name in a data label, and your data is in multiple series with one category (the 'Edward Su'). Put your data in one series, and populate the x axis categories array with the names.

Comment: @CrunchyTopping : you are right, I didn't explain my issue clearly enough. I've added what I want exactly, which is to show type_1 next to the bars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to use annotations. It's easier to use **dataLabels**. They are placed in place you want by default and you can display in them whatever you want using **dataLabels.formatter**.
Of course, you can disable xAxis labels now.

This is an example (I defined an array **labels** and return from it, but you can return values from your **type_1** list):

```
library(highcharter)

#create dataframe
data <- data.frame(
  type_1 = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"),
  type_2 = c("1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2"),
  n = c(5,8,10,4,7,9))
data

# create chart
highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series(data, type = "bar", hcaes(x = type_1, group = type_2, y = n), dataLabels = list(
  enabled = TRUE,
  formatter = JS(
    "function() {
      var labels = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
      return labels[this.point.x];
    }"
  ))) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = data$type_1)
```

[image: Final effect with above code]

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.dataLabels

Pure JS example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nrtax718

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted! Do you know if it is possible not to manually specify ['a', 'b', 'c'], but to make it dependent on the actual series? In my complete barchart users can select which groups they want to see, so it won't always be a, b and c.

Comment: And one more question: in the final example I would like to stack te bars (I have adjusten my original question to include this). I assumed it would work the same way, but if I just your solution to a stacked bar the labels are shown inside of the bars.

Comment: So, you don't want dataLabels but stackLabels, right? https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.stackLabels

Is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ehtp0ks1

Do you know JS? I am beginner with R so it would be easier to first achieve the final chart in pure JS, then rewrite it to R.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with JS, but I do have some experience transforming it to R. So if you have an example in JS that would already be super helpfull! And I guess I do want the stackLabels, but is stead of the value, show the label.

Comment: Hmm, I created "labels" array with sample content. Can you just parse your data and create a similar array depending on your series?
In Highcharts, in yAxis.stackLabels.formatter, you don't have access to specific series, but as I said, I think the simplest solution is to write your own parser which takes labels from your series data and returns them in stackLabels.formatter (I am not sure if you understand what I mean - if not, can you provide me a sample data in this jsFiddle? - https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ehtp0ks1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using annotations.

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

data <- data.frame(
  type_1 = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"),
  type_2 = c("1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2"),
  n = c(5,8,10,4,7,9) )
```

Start defining a column `id` to identify uniquely each bar.

```
(data$id <- mapply(function(x,y) paste0(x,y), data$type_1, data$type_2))

# [1] "a1" "a2" "b1" "b2" "c1" "c2"
```

Then add to the dataset a list with the labels for bars.
Each bar is referenced by its `id`.

```
data <- data %>%
  mutate(labels = map(1:nrow(.), function(k) {
       list(point=as.character(id[k]), text=as.character(n[k]), 
            backgroundColor="red", distance=5, style=list(fontSize="16px"))
       })
  )

# This is label for the first bar
data$labels[[1]]
# $point
# [1] "a1"
# 
# $text
# [1] "5"
# 
# $backgroundColor
# [1] "red"
# 
# $distance
# [1] 5
# 
# $style
# $style$fontSize
# [1] "16px"
```

At last, add labels using annotations

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series(data, type = "bar", hcaes(x = "type_1", group = "type_2", y = "n")) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = unique(data$type_1)) %>%  
  hc_annotations( list(labels=data$labels) )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I prefer the formatting using dataLabel that raf18seb suggests, but this definitely also does the trick (although I would like the a / b / c to be shown, and not the values, but I think that would just be a minor adjustment)